# Compare highway and avoid highway distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I would like to compare distance when using highway and when avoiding highway but I have no idea how to do it. My code is calculating distance between two points and the price based on distance. If highway checkbox is checked it should calculate different price but when there is no highway the price should remain the same.

This is the code

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.521573, 16.441015),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeID: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var vehicle = document.getElementById('vehicle').value;

  //var highway = document.getElementById('highway').checked;
  //var round = document.getElementById('return').checked;

  var distanceInput = document.getElementById('distance');
  var timeInput = document.getElementById('time');
  var priceInput = document.getElementById('price');

  var request, price;

  if (document.getElementById('highway').checked) {
    request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidHighways: false
    };

  } else {
     request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidHighways: true
    };

  }

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

      if (document.getElementById('highway').checked)
        dist_highway = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
      else
        dist = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;

      distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;

      var hours = parseInt( response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 3600) % 24;
      var minutes = parseInt( response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 60) % 60;
      timeInput.value = hours + "h " + minutes + "m";


      if (vehicle == 'van') {
        if ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) < '30' ) {
          price = (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 1.19;
        } else {
          price = (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 0.93;
        }
      } else if (vehicle == 'personal') {
        if ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) < '30' ) {
          price = (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 1.32;
        } else {
          price = (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000) * 1.06;
        }
      }

      if (document.getElementById('highway').checked && vehicle == 'personal' ) {
        price *= 1.3;
      } else if (document.getElementById('highway').checked && vehicle == 'van' ) {
        price *= 1.5;
      };

      if (document.getElementById('return').checked) {
        price *= 1.7;

      };

      priceInput.value = price.toFixed(2) + "€";

    }
  });
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

After AlexB's explanation this is my function. Problem solved.

```
function calcDist(start, end) {
  var requestHighway, request, distHighway, dist;
  var dirService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  requestHighway = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidHighways: false
    };

  request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidHighways: true
    };

  dirService.route(requestHighway, function(response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      distHighway = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
      distHighway = distHighway.toFixed(2);

    }
  });

  dirService.route(request, function(response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      dist = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
      dist = distHighway.toFixed(2);

    }
  });

  if (distHighway - dist == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried to do that (compare the distance)?  I would think you would first need to get both values, your code currently only gets one.

Comment: @geocodezip there are some routes that don't have highway but my code still counts the highway price. I would like to compare if the lengths of highway and avoid highway routes are the same then there is no highway :)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @geocodezip sorry but don't understand

Comment: What he means is : To COMPARE distance, you need distance WITH highways and distance WITHOUT highways. In the code you've shown above, you compute only the distance with OR without highways depending on your checkbox "highway" is checked. However, you need both distances, then, substract them to get the difference.

Comment: Thanks @AlexB, I managed to solve the problem after your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After AlexB's explanation this is my function. Problem solved.

```
function calcDist(start, end) {
  var requestHighway, request, distHighway, dist;
  var dirService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  requestHighway = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidHighways: false
    };

  request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidHighways: true
    };

  dirService.route(requestHighway, function(response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      distHighway = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
      distHighway = distHighway.toFixed(2);

    }
  });

  dirService.route(request, function(response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      dist = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
      dist = distHighway.toFixed(2);

    }
  });

  if (distHighway - dist == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```